# Or operator in Conditional attribute in C#

Tags: c#

In C# we can differentiate code execution depending on the type of build. By default we have Debug and Release types defined.
We can do it using the `#if` directive:

```
#if DEBUG
    public void Foo()
    { ... }
#endif
```

But we can also use `Conditional` attribute:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Foo()
{ ... }
```

The second solution is even claimed to be more maintainable (see: Effective C# by Bill Wagner).

My question is - how can I use the `Conditional` attribute with many build configurations? Is it possible to somehow use the `or` operator? I ask because I want some Foo method to be executed both in, for example, the DEBUG and BAR build configurations. What then?

Comment: Just apply it multiple times, as shown in the example in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, it's possible (`AttributeUsageAttribute` for `ConditionalAttribute` has `AllowMultiple` set to `true`) however please note that your two examples behave very different (even if you move your `#if DEBUG` inside method body) when there are parameters involved.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Can you elaborate on how they will perform differently?

Comment: With `[Conditional("")]` parameters won't be evaluated if call will be omitted while with `#if` (inside method body) parameters evaluation is always performed (but function call may be elided by compiler because body is empty). For example: after `Foo(++counter)` (with attribute) `counter` is not incremented. It works like _old style_ C macros like `ASSERT()` where expression is simply replaced with an empty line.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use multiple comma separated conditional attributes like

```
[Conditional("DEBUG"), Conditional("BAR")]
```

and it will be exactly your desired behaviour - they will be logically ORed together.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Note the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z371wyft.aspx#Conditional) also answers the obvious next question: How do you AND `Conditionals`?

Comment: The AND is really there but I don't like the way it is done because you end up nesting methods which may be, accidently, called somewhere else - violating the conditionals attributes. Maybe wrapping your AND conditional in your own attribute give you a safer result.